# Can't locate Parallel/ForkManager.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, perl, cluster-computing, perl-module

I'm running a pipeline which includes running this CP3_Opti.pl Perl script that uses Parallel::ForkManager module (https://github.com/lyl8086/RADscripts/blob/master/RADassembler/bin/CP3_Opti.pl) by submitting it to sge on a remote cluster (CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804, perl v5.16.3). It gives an error:

> Can't locate Parallel/ForkManager.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
>   /home/isabolic/perl5/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5
>   /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
>   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
>   /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
>   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl **/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl**
>   /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at
>   /home/isabolic/bin//bin/CP3_Opti.pl line 5. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at /home/isabolic/bin//bin/CP3_Opti.pl line 5. Error in local
>   assembly, exiting...

However, the Parallel::ForkManager is actually installed and in the @INC path at **/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl**:

```
cpan -D Parallel:ForkManager

        Y/YA/YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.02.tar.gz
        /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm
        Installed: 1.18
        CPAN:      2.02  Not up to date
        Yanick Champoux (YANICK)
        yanick+cpan@babyl.dyndns.org
```

The module was installed by admin and I do not have root access, but the module itself, as well as all path directories, have read permissions enabled for everyone. When I run `perl -e "use Parallel::ForkManager"` in terminal there is no errors. PERL5LIB variable in my .bashrc file contains all the directories listed above in @INC.

Adding the `use lib "usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl"` before line 5 in CP3_Opti.pl (use Parallel::ForkManager) didn't help. Neither did changing the shebang line in the script from `#!/usr/bin/env perl` to `#!/usr/bin/perl` didin't help, got the same error.

When trying to install this module with cpan in my local Perl library I get bunch of errors as it's failing multiple test, which was the original reason for /usr installation.

Anybody know what might be the problem?

**EDIT:**
`ls -ld /usr /usr/share /usr/share/perl5 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm` from the shell gives:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root   155 Kol  8 16:01 /usr
drwxr-xr-x. 147 root root  4096 Stu 21 08:52 /usr/share
drwxr-xr-x   49 root root  4096 Ruj 13 20:11 /usr/share/perl5
drwxr-xr-x   44 root root  4096 Stu  6 17:12 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    28 Stu  6 17:12 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 26027 Ožu 30  2016 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm
```

and `system('ls -ld /usr /usr/share /usr/share/perl5 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm >&2')` from script:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm: No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root  155 Oct 10 10:13 /usr
drwxr-xr-x. 133 root root 4096 Oct 10 08:40 /usr/share
drwxr-xr-x   48 root root 4096 Oct 10 08:38 /usr/share/perl5
drwxr-xr-x   32 root root 4096 Oct 10 08:42 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
```

Comment: Have you checked that `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm` exists and is readable by the user that tries to `use` it? Also, did you mean `use lib "/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl"`? This is vastly different from `use lib "usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl"` ! If it "works from the shell" as you say, what is the output of `which perl`? Compare that to the shebang line of your script.

Comment: Inspect `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm`, it probably doesn't have the content you think it does.

Comment: If you run perl in the shell - which version do you get? It's not all that uncommon for a `/usr/local/bin/perl` to exist and be used first in the path.

Comment: `which perl` gives `/usr/bin/perl`
`/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm` exists and it is readable `-rw-r--r--`. I checked it out with `cat` and it looks fine. 
As for `use lib "/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl"` and `use lib "usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl"`neither works, got the same error with both.

Comment: I think Perl stops looking through `@INC` at the first unreadable directory. Maybe that's what happens here?

Comment: Note that your use line is missing the leading `'/'`, should be `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl`

Comment: Please provide the output of `\ls -ld /usr /usr/share /usr/share/perl5 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm` (run from the shell) and `system('ls -ld /usr /usr/share /usr/share/perl5 /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Parallel/ForkManager.pm >&2')` (added to the script)

Comment: @ikegami I appended the output to the original question. Could this be due to the module not being installed on all the nodes, but just the access node?

Comment: The link counts and time stamps are all different. The file system used by your script is different than the file system used by your interactive session are different. Couldn't tell you why, but it could be that they are running on different machines.

Comment: I contacted my admin and he installed the module on all cluster nodes and now it's running with no errors. Thanks everyone. @ikegami please post your answer about checking the used file system and that they are running on different machines so I can accept your answer.